# two radio buttons not do it correctly

Tags: android, radio-button

I have problem my android app
I have two buttons if i click at the first its work ok,but if i click at the second its do his job and fist job
this is the code:

for the id

```
rbYes = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbYes);
    rbNo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbNo);
```

for the method

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(buttonView.getId()){
    case R.id.rbYes:
        flag=true;
        etLastHourse.setEnabled(flag);
        etLastHourse.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        etLastGPA.setEnabled(flag);
        etLastGPA.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    break;
    case R.id.rbNo:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        flag=false;
        etLastHourse.setEnabled(flag);
        etLastHourse.setEnabled(flag);
        etLastHourse.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        etLastGPA.setEnabled(flag);
        etLastGPA.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);



    break;

    }
}
```

for the xml

```
  <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNo"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="no"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbYes"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="yes" />
```

Comment: paste your layout xml file? what you do with this radio button , brief about the action?

Comment: put your radiobutton inside radiogroups...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press one button first, you toggle that button only

When you press the other button, you toggle both buttons. Therefore your `onCheckedChanged` is checked once the first time you press one of the radiobuttons, and two times the next time.

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
   // Is the button now checked?
   boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

   // Check which radio button was clicked
   switch(view.getId()) {
      case R.id.radio_pirates:
         if (checked)
            // Do all things here for this button
         break;
      case R.id.radio_ninjas:
         if (checked)
            // Do all things here for this button
         break;
}
```

Just do the things you want to if the button is checked.